# Winston Logger - NodeJs Debug console logs not showing in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, output, console.log, winston

I'm using VSCode debugger and winston logger for NodeJS, but can't see output from application unless I specify external terminal like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
]
```

Is there way to see that output in output window, like when i start code using CodeRunner plugin?

Comment: What node version are you using

Comment: At the moment it's 9.0.0. But it was same with older. I wouldn't go in that direction, this should be VSCode related issue/feature

Comment: 9.0 should be using the inspector protocol, I believe. . . only reason I asked, (but debugging wouldn't work at all if that wasn't set correctly)

Comment: Wait, when you say output you're talking about console.log statements right?

Comment: windows/linux might also be important

Comment: yes, I mean on console.log(). I'm on macOs

Comment: Does `integratedTerminal` work ? it should output to the terminal tab

Comment: Additionally, you're not running any sort of program that clusters your app, are you? Have you tried running the bare minimum of a program ? I.e., server.js just `console.log('test')`

Comment: When I'm using integrated terminal i get this: node --inspect-brk=27768 server.js
node: bad option: --inspect-brk=27768

Comment: My console log works perfectly in external terminal, but i would like to have it in one place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162185/discussion-between-cody-g-and-josip).

Answer (score 163, accepted):

When using a logger that outputs to

`process.stdout.write`

you can use

`"outputCapture": "std"` in the launch config to also capture that.

Comment: Seems this is an old and accepted answer. As I write this comment in 2022 just this solution didn't work with VSCode version 1.62.2 and winston version 3.8.1. I had to make sure I set the log level to 'debug' in the Console transport to get it working. Something like this:
 `transports: [ new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'debug' })]`

Comment: Level debug would just ensure something like log.debug  gets output. If you did a higher level you'd have to use log.info, etc.

Comment: what I mean is, just the VS Code Launch config didn't work standalonely. You have to also set the log level to 'debug', in order to see even log.info or log.error logs in Debug Console of VSCode. This is weird but somehow there must be some correlation. It doesn't print even errors or infos if the log level is not set to debug, while you're running the application in debug mode on VS Code